# proxy server allows texts but not images

Tags: python, web, proxy, server

Im trying to make a web proxy in python which is able to get the texts from the main server but not the images. The url http://gaia.cs.umass.edu/wireshark-labs/HTTP-wireshark-file1.html contains a line of text i am able to view in the browser and the url http://images.mid-day.com/images/2017/feb/15-salman-khan.jpg contains a image which i am not able to display in the browser. Im using Google Chrome. Below is my code. (I have hard-coded the hostname of the the image url for this post). Can anyone help me fix the problem.

```
from socket import *
client= socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
proxy_port = 8880
client.bind(("", proxy_port ))
client.listen(10)

while 1:
    client_connection, client_address = CLIENT.accept()
    request = client_connection.recv(102400).decode()

    if request.startswith("GET"):
        try:
            print(request)
            web = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
            web.connect(("images.mid-day.com", 80))
            web.send(request.encode())
            reply = web.recv(102400).decode()
            print(reply)
            client_connection.send(reply.encode())
            web.close()
        except:
            print("illegal req")
client.close()
```

This is my get request from the browser:

[image: This is my get request from the browser]

Comment: is there any feedback?

Answer (score 2):

You have only read 102400 bytes from the upstream server, but the image response is (at least) 567702 bytes. You should read until upstream shutdown connection, besides use `sendall()` to make sure all data has been sent:

```
reply = b''
while True:
    data = web.recv(4096)
    if not data:
        break
    reply += data
client_connection.sendall(reply)
```